# Programmatically select text in Gtk::TextView using Gtkmm

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, gtkmm3

How can I select text in `Gtk::TextView`:

- starting from where the cursor is
- `n` number of characters backwards

The documentation from `developer.gnome.org` doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selection isn't done in the `Gtk::TextView` itself but in the associated `Gtk::TextBuffer`. While I'm not sure why exactly this design choice was done I'm at least clear about the consequence: Selections may be shared between multiple `Gtk::TextView`s when they share the same buffer. This may be desirable or not but it's how “they” have done it.

The buffer of a `Gtk::TextView` can be obtained with

[**Glib::RefPtr< TextBuffer >   get_buffer ()**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TextView.html#a309c03880870321b6f19c89ffe4319be)

> Returns the Gtk::TextBuffer being displayed by this text view.
>
> The reference count on the buffer is not incremented; the caller of this function won’t own a new reference.

Then, the `Gtk::TextBuffer` provides

[**void Gtk::TextBuffer::select_range   (const iterator&    ins, const iterator&    bound)**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TextBuffer.html#a88b0a4096add7e8ea77098ffa5973a7f)

> This function moves the “insert” and “selection_bound” marks simultaneously.
>
> If you move them in two steps with `move_mark()`, you will temporarily select a region in between their old and new locations, which can be pretty inefficient since the temporarily-selected region will force stuff to be recalculated. This function moves them as a unit, which can be optimized.
>
> `ins` Where to put the “insert” mark.
>
> `bound`   Where to put the “selection_bound” mark.

The current cursor position can be obtained with

[**Glib::RefPtr Gtk::TextBuffer::get_insert()**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TextBuffer.html#a4b92f14603f572f99daf0c86abd1b9ad)

> Returns the mark that represents the cursor (insertion point).
>
> Equivalent to calling get_mark() to get the mark named “insert”, but very slightly more efficient, and involves less typing.

The returned `Gtk::TextMark` can be “converted” to a `Gtk::TextIter` by using

[**TextIter Gtk::TextMark::get_iter()**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TextMark.html#a1ed8d8769cf46a34769fb4ec76c50371).

Additionally, `Gtk::TextBuffer` provides a variety of `get_iter_at` functions to get the `Gtk::TextBuffer::iterator`s for distinct parameters.

---

**A note in general:**

To learn a powerful widget API by the reference manual, is something I would consider as tedious.

In the case of gtkmm, there is a serious alternative:

[**Programming with gtkmm 3**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/index-info.html.en)

(which is available in other languages as well).

Chapter 11 is about [**TextView**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/chapter-textview.html.en) and might help to get the “big picture”.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Additionally I used `get_iter_at_offset()` and `property_cursor_position().get_value()` methods to get the proper "bound" (2nd argument for `select_range()`

Comment: I have to admit, though, I had to go through the header files to get what I wanted. The docs and the tutorial seem very lacking.